# How to hide code on a button press from my coworkers in a clever way?

Tags: c#

I have the following code I want to run on a windows forms application some of my coworkers are using:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

if (userName.ToLower().Contains("trollthisguy#1") || 
    userName.ToLower().Contains("trollthisguy#2"))
{
    //initiate rickroll 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
}
```

Right now, I have this code in the main form .cs file on a button pressed event. Is there a clever way for me to hide this? I want to make them work for it... :)

Comment: You may want to update your CV while you're at it.  But I wouldn't mention this particular "accomplishment".  ;)

Comment: If they're c# programmers, they will notice pretty fast.

Comment: You could put it in the form designer partial class, it will be slightly less obvious there :) Grega's suggestion is best for stealth though, I guess.

Comment: If you do this, you will more than likely be fired for spreading a "virus" around your company.  This is not a prank that should be done...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It depends on the company. I once wrote an application to reverse the mouse by applying `-2*Δ` changes as the mouse moved in order to prank a co-worker, and I know another co-worker who copied my idea at his next company. :)

Comment: If your coworkers are under 60 then just putting it into a windows forms app should be all the deterrent you need.

Comment: I also did this kind of thing way back in the day. But that was also the era when Microsoft and other software companies were intentionally putting "easter eggs" in their production software (before [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)). In this day and age, where security is of the utmost importance, I would strongly suggest you *not* do this.

Comment: I did put it in the designer partial class. Greg's option trumps what I cmae up with though haha

Answer (score 5):

Create a DLL with a class with some familiar name, like `String` and some familiar static function, like `IsNullOrEmpty` and start the process inside:

```
public class String
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
```

Then, reference your DLL and in your button pressed event, do something very simple just to call this function. Something like:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyButton.Content) {
    // ....
}
```

Maybe they won't notice. ;)

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiice